# EmberJS API questions using PHP

Tags: php, ember.js

I'm using Laravel/PHP to output some JSON for Ember to pick up.... a couple of things here.

First, my PHP looks like this (is there another way to send the data)

```
        return Response::json([
        'articles'  => $articles->toArray()
        ], $statusCode);
```

This is what I am used to doing.

```
      foreach($articles as $article) {
         $response['articles'][] = [ 
            'id'    =>  $article->id,
            'body'  =>  $article->body,
            'title' =>  $article->title
        ];
     }

         return Response::json([
        'articles'  => $articles->toArray()
        ], $statusCode);
```

The first PHP snippet works fine, but the second does not. I get all kinds of errors about resource types by Ember.

Next question is for Ember heads. Right now I am getting everything working with `RESTAdapter` but should I be using `JSONAPIAdapter` instead? When I try to get it working with `JSONAPIAdapter` and `JSONAPISerializer` I get this **error**

> One or more of the following keys must be present: \"data\",
>   \"errors\", \"meta

. I can get that error to go away but then I get an error about an undefined type or an unknown resource.

Comment: Show the `return` part of second snippet. Second question - jsonapi must contain `data` key as  “primary data” http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-top-level

Comment: I updated the post to show the return user1156168....I had that in the array but I think my PHP was wrong, I'll test again and see what I can find. Do you think I need a serializer or would that be overkill in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

Its not mandatory to use JSONAPIAdapter, but if you have control over the API then you can very well using it. API response should follow the format (http://jsonapi.org/format/)

Sample format for single resource object,

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      // ... this article's attributes
    }        
  }
}
```

Sample format for multiple resource objects,

```
{      
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "2",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Rails is Omakase"
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: very good kumkanillam, thank you for the answer. The format works perfectly with JSONAPI!