# Unable to serialize backend response in ember data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to access the pagination variables in the response such as page_number, total_pages inside my controller as I have introduced this feature just now to this legacy code in the backend and now I am stuck how can I read those data and go further.

My serializer code

```
import DS from 'ember-data';


var underscore = Ember.String.underscore;
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    rules: {
      embedded: 'always'
    },

    test_cases: {
      serialize: "id",
      deserialize: 'records'
    },
  },
  keyForRelationship: function (rawKey) {
    return underscore(rawKey) + "_id";
  }
})
```

route.js

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { hash } from 'rsvp'
import ResetScrollMixin from 'admin-frontend/mixins/reset-scroll-mixin'
export default Route.extend(ResetScrollMixin, {

  model(params) {
    return hash({
      ruleSetVersions: this.store.query('rule-set-version', {
        rule_set_id: params.rule_set_id,
        is_archived: false,
        page: '1'
      }),
      ruleSet: this.store.findRecord('rule-set', params.rule_set_id)
    })
  }
});
```

And response json looks like

```
{
    "page_number": 1,
    "page_size": 5,
    "rule_set_versions": [{
        "id": 930,
        "last_updated_by": 1,
        "created_by": 1,
        "default_rule_id": 963,
        "is_live": true,
        "is_archived": false,
        "start_time": "2020-12-30T18:30:00Z",
        "rule_set_id": 11,
        "rules": [{
            "id": 963,
            "priority": 10000001,
            "conditions": [],
            "results": [{
                "id": 59,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "00",
                "rule_id": 963,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:10:41Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:10:41Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:10:32Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:10:32Z"
        }, {
            "id": 971,
            "priority": 1,
            "conditions": [{
                "id": 57,
                "comparator": "equal_to",
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 971,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "datatype": "text",
                    "id": 33,
                    "name": "edd_con",
                    "property_category": "condition",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "validations": {}
                },
                "created_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:04Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:04Z"
            }],
            "results": [{
                "id": 66,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 971,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:10Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-12-23T09:05:10Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2020-12-23T09:04:54Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-12-23T09:04:54Z"
        }],
        "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:10:32Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-23T09:06:04Z"
    }, {
        "id": 932,
        "last_updated_by": 1,
        "created_by": 1,
        "default_rule_id": 969,
        "is_live": true,
        "is_archived": false,
        "start_time": "2020-11-25T18:30:00Z",
        "rule_set_id": 11,
        "rules": [{
            "id": 969,
            "priority": 10000001,
            "conditions": [],
            "results": [{
                "id": 64,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "1000",
                "rule_id": 969,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:53:58Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:53:58Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:53:49Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:53:49Z"
        }, {
            "id": 970,
            "priority": 1,
            "conditions": [{
                "id": 56,
                "comparator": "equal_to",
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 970,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "datatype": "text",
                    "id": 33,
                    "name": "edd_con",
                    "property_category": "condition",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "validations": {}
                },
                "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:11Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:11Z"
            }],
            "results": [{
                "id": 65,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 970,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:16Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:16Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:03Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:54:03Z"
        }],
        "created_at": "2020-11-25T11:53:49Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-11-25T11:55:12Z"
    }, {
        "id": 934,
        "last_updated_by": 1,
        "created_by": 1,
        "default_rule_id": 974,
        "is_live": false,
        "is_archived": false,
        "start_time": "2020-12-30T18:30:00Z",
        "rule_set_id": 11,
        "rules": [{
            "id": 974,
            "priority": 10000001,
            "conditions": [],
            "results": [{
                "id": 69,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "00",
                "rule_id": 974,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z"
        }, {
            "id": 976,
            "priority": 1,
            "conditions": [{
                "id": 60,
                "comparator": "equal_to",
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 976,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "datatype": "text",
                    "id": 33,
                    "name": "edd_con",
                    "property_category": "condition",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:05Z",
                    "validations": {}
                },
                "created_at": "2021-03-12T16:18:04Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-12T16:18:04Z"
            }],
            "results": [{
                "id": 71,
                "operator": null,
                "value": "100",
                "rule_id": 976,
                "rule_set_metadatum": {
                    "created_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "datatype": "integer",
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "edd_result",
                    "property_category": "result",
                    "updated_at": "2020-11-18T10:01:38Z",
                    "validations": {
                        "max": 99999,
                        "min": 0
                    }
                },
                "created_at": "2021-03-12T16:18:10Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-03-12T16:18:10Z"
            }],
            "created_at": "2021-03-12T16:17:55Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-03-12T16:17:55Z"
        }],
        "created_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-03-11T10:55:44Z"
    }],
    "total_entries": 3,
    "total_pages": 1
}
```

I am able to read and parse all the data inside the rule_set_versions array but I am unable to access the pagination params that are out side it.

Ember noob here.

Comment: Any help please unable to move ahead with this one.

Comment: Not an expert, but I guess you should go in this direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876408/how-to-serialize-ember-paginated-data / https://davidtang.io/2018-04-06-extracting-metadata-from-a-custom-api-with-ember-data/. If that helps I'll make it an answer